How can I adjust the pencil width in Gimp?
How can I adjust the pencil width in Gimp ?
When I used the pencil, I got this mess.


Close voters please appreciate that 'Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.' is allowable on AU. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Go to Windows → Dockable Dialogues → Tool Options, extend the inner window (if needed) and you will see the option to modify the size as the first option listed (default is 51,00)
Normally, tool options are displayed in a window attached under the Toolbox as soon as you activate a tool. If they are not, you can access them from the image menu bar through Windows → Dockable Windows → Tool Options which opens the option window of the selected tool
reference

GIMP Version Flathub 2.10.38

I found Dockable Dialogs, but no Dockable Windows.

@AndrewK https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Getting-the-Tool-options-back-once-for-all

Yes, it's under Windows=>Dockable Dialogues

@jeffas Thanks, I found it.
